# Changing a null string to an empty string in select statment

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 table that has a string column in which empty values are sometimes stored as `NULL` and other times as an empty string.

I am doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` on this column and I am getting all the distinct values + NULL + empty string. But what I would like is to check if the value is NULL and return an empty string instead. So the result set would be all the distinct values + empty string (if any values were null or an empty string).

But how can I do this in a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Check out ISNULL() in the [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Syntax:

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

Example:

```
Select ISNULL(myfield1,'') from mytable1
```

Answer (score 12):

Look at the [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function. It returns the first non `null` value passed in.

```
COALESCE( myValue , '' )
```

This will return myValue if it is not null, or an empty string (`''`), if it is.

It is less verbose than using many `ISNULL()` and `IF` clauses and as such can be easier to read.

Comment: A big difference between `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is that the return type for `COALESCE` is determined by datatype precedence.  So `SELECT COALESCE(null, 2, current_timestamp)` will return the value `1900-01-03 00:00:00.000`, and `SELECT COALESCE(null, 'a',  current_timestamp)` results in a type conversion error.

Comment: Why would you need to use `ISNULL()` with an `IF` statement?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(columnname, '') FROM table WHERE ...
```